# Оцените качество кода

Tags: php

```
require_once('adodb/adodb.inc.php');

class adoDbConnector
{

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
    if (self::$instance == NULL)
    {
        self::$instance = new adoDbConnector();
    }

    return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct() { }

    public function __clone()
    {
        trigger_error('No __clone()!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        trigger_error('No __wakeup()!', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    public function connect($connectionType, $connectionData)
    {
        switch($connectionType)
        {
            case 0: 
            return self::generalConnect($connectionData);
            break;

                    case 1: 
            return self::dsnConnect($connectionData);
            break;

                    case 2: 
            return self::xmlConnect($connectionData);
            break;

                    default:
            throw new Exception('Wrong type of connection!');
        }
    }

    private static function generalConnect($connectionData)
    {   
        if(is_array($connectionData))
        {
            $conn = &ADONewConnection($connectionData[0]);

            $conn->PConnect($connectionData[1], $connectionData[2], 
                                $connectionData[3], $connectionData[4]);

            return $conn;
        }
        else throw new Exception('Wrong type of connection data, must be an array!');
    }

    private static function dsnConnect($connectionData)
    {       
        if(is_string($connectionData))
        {
            $conn = ADONewConnection($connectionData);

            return $conn;
        }
        else throw new Exception('Wrong type of connection data, must be a string!');
    }

    private static function xmlConnect($connectionData)
    {
        if(is_string($connectionData) && file_exists($connectionData))
        {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($connectionData);

            foreach($xml as $x)
            {
                $connArr[] = trim($x);
            }

            $conn = &ADONewConnection($connArr[0]);

            $conn->PConnect($connArr[1], $connArr[2], $connArr[3], $connArr[4]);

            return $conn;
        }
        else throw new Exception('Wrong file name or connection type!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Лично меня смущают ссылки... Зачем?

Comment: Лично меня смущает, что Вы пытаетесь создать Singleton таким ужасным образом. Почитайте [здесь][1]
[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/92217/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD-singleton

Comment: меня пустой конструктор, почему допустим не выполнять connect при создании экземпляра класса, к тому же можно сделать его опциональным

Comment: FLK, поясните пожалуйста про опциональность, каким образом? Что именно? 
Да, действительно, возможно будет лучше выполнять его при создании экземпляра, хотя тут еще нужно подумать, но спасибо большое за идею. :)  

На счет ссылок - пример из мануала, в принципе они не нужны. 

Спасибо за ссылку на синглтон.

Comment: Они не в принципе не нужны, они там не нужны вообще. Одно дело пример, другое реальный код

Comment: ясно, этот косяк осознал.

Comment: Комментариев не нашел. В общем-то поэтому дальше оценивать сложно - о смысле некоторых объектов (переменных, функций) можно либо только догадываться, либо долго втыкать в код. А хороший стиль нужен именно потому, чтобы не заниматься ни тем, ни другим.

Comment: @Archont12 я имел виду конструкцию типа 

          __construct($connectionData=false)

таким образом при создании экземпляра класса если указаны параметры сразу устанавливаем соединение, если new без параметров то просто создаем. опционально, я имел ввиду что можно передавать параметр, а можно и не передавать.

Comment: Так красивее. :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же отсутствие комментариев к коду.

Возможно стоит обратить внимание на стандарт
[CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) или выбрать любой [другой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38214/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Хромает форматирование
2. Да и вот такой стиль (перевод `{` на новую строку) честно говоря убивает

Comment: Стиль мне тоже не нравиться, но тем не менее, как я замечал - большинство java, C#, PHP(пишущих на Zend'e) разработчиков пишут именно так, так что стиль это всего-лишь ИМХО.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, это ужасно, что пишут так.

Comment: Действительно пишу на Zend'e и С#. )

Comment: Мне приходилось заниматься аудитом кода в компании, использующей стиль RSDN (там как раз Allman-style). Так вот, когда 12 часов подряд вычитываешь чужой код - этот стиль офигенно удобен, а значит и в плане сопровождения тоже. Хотя по жизни я использую K&R (1TBS). Так что это просто вопрос внутренний соглашений в команде разработчиков.

Comment: @northerner, не знаю, не знаю.. 

Вот такой стиль:

    if ( condition ) {
       // some code
    }

Гораздо лучше. Опять же - ИМХО.

Comment: @exec, ну так я и написал

 > Хотя по жизни я использую K&R (1TBS).

И одно время я был яростным евангелистом K&R. Но, когда поработал с другими стилями, к расстановке фигурных скобок отношусь спокойно. Лишь бы стиль был везде одинаков.

Comment: Я просто не знаю обозначения стилей, поэтому написал.